# Django models timestamp in MYSQL Db

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to store time as unix timestamp in my MYSQL database, I have django project with model:

```
date = models.DateField()
```

But I didn't find any `models.Timestamp()`
or anything similiar. Is there a way to create timestamp column for MYSQL Db in Django? I found some articles here on stack but they are 5+ years old so there might a be a better solution now.

Comment: Usually a `DateTimeField` is used, a timestamp can represent only a subset of the datetime values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django, one usually uses a [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) for that. It is a column that thus stores a combination of date and time.

One can let Django automatically intialize (or update) the timestamp if the record is constructed or updated with [**`auto_now_add=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) to initialize it when the record was created, and [**`auto_now=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) to update. So it is a common pattern to see a (base)model like:

```
class TimestampModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

such that subclasses of the `TimestampModel` thus have two extra columns `created` and `updated` that store the time when the object was created and last updated respectively.

A `datetime` column has a larger range, as is specified in the [*MySQL* documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html):

> The `DATETIME` type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays `DATETIME` values in `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'` format. The **supported range is `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'` to
>   `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'`**.
>
> The `TIMESTAMP` data type is used for values that contain both date
>   and time parts. **`TIMESTAMP` has a range of `'1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC` to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC`**.